# selecting points within a geometrical shape in a grid with R

Tags: r, plot, geometry

Here is my problem. 
I have an hypercube I built using the following codes:

```
X <- seq (-1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2),length.out=100)
Y <- seq (-sqrt(2)/(2*sqrt(3)),sqrt(2)/sqrt(3),length.out=100)
Z <- seq (-1/(2*sqrt(3)),sqrt(3)/2,length.out=100)
grid <- data.frame (expand.grid(X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z))
```

Then, I would delete from the grid data.frame all the points that are not located within the tetrahedron defined by the following coordinates:

```
w : (0,0,sqrt(3)/2)
x : (0,sqrt(2)/sqrt(3),-1/(2*sqrt(3)))
y : (-1/sqrt(2),-sqrt(2)/(2*sqrt(3)),-1/(2*sqrt(3)))
z : (1/sqrt(2),-sqrt(2)/(2*sqrt(3)),-1/(2*sqrt(3)))
```

I do not find a away to do this without howfully long codes. Can anyone help me please
Thanks !!!

Comment: I seem to remember some discussion on r-help about finding points outside a convex hull

Answer (score 1):

Package `ptinpoly` has a function `pip3d` to find wether a point is in a polyhedron or not.

```
library(ptinpoly)
X <- seq(-1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2),length.out=10)  #I used a smaller dataset here
Y <- seq(-sqrt(2)/(2*sqrt(3)),sqrt(2)/sqrt(3),length.out=10)
Z <- seq(-1/(2*sqrt(3)),sqrt(3)/2,length.out=10)
# The query points has to be inputted as a matrix.
grid <- as.matrix(expand.grid(X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z))

w <- c(0,0,sqrt(3)/2)
x <- c(0,sqrt(2)/sqrt(3),-1/(2*sqrt(3)))
y <- c(-1/sqrt(2),-sqrt(2)/(2*sqrt(3)),-1/(2*sqrt(3)))
z <- c(1/sqrt(2),-sqrt(2)/(2*sqrt(3)),-1/(2*sqrt(3)))
# The matrix of vertices
tetra_vert <- matrix(c(w,x,y,z),byrow=TRUE,nrow=4)
# The matrix of faces (each row correspond to a vector of vertices linked by a face.
tetra_faces <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
                        1,2,4,
                        1,3,4,
                        2,3,4),byrow=TRUE,nrow=4)
inout <- pip3d(tetra_vert, tetra_faces, grid)
```

The result is a vector of integers, `0` means the point fall on a face, `1` that it is inside the polyhedron, `-1` outside.

The solution of your problem is therefore:

```
grid[inout%in%c(0,1),]
```

Answer (score 0):

make planes which form the tetrahedron and compare if a point is on the right side of each of the planes.

pointers: think of calculating dot products with the plane normal and such. One option is to draw a vector from tetrahedron point to each corner, 4 in total and 1 vector from point to point and then use dotproducts and whatnot to see if the point-point vector is within the 4 others.

the point is probably within the tetrahedron if vector to it can be expressed as a sum of non negative multiples of the corner vectors and the vector short enough.